# Proving that a closed simple polygon in the plane is convex if and only if all the interior angles measure less than or equal to $\pi$ radians

Tags: geometry, reference-request, polygons, convex-geometry

> Consider a closed simple polygon in the plane. It is intuitively obvious that the polygon is convex if and only if all the interior angles measure less than or equal to $\pi$ radians.
>
> I have never seen a rigorous proof of this fact and I was wondering if anyone could provide such a proof.

A related question:

> Given a concave polygon (or more generally a higher dimensional polytope), how can we prove that there will always be two ***vertices*** of the polygon which cannot be joined by a line lying entirely inside the polygon?

Comment: The answer to your related question is by definition. Concave = not convex, and a polytope is convex iff every line segment between any two points in the polytope lies entirely inside the polyhedron. Invert that condition (i.e., "there exists a line segment that exits and reenters the polytope"), and you necessarily (and sufficiently) have a concave polytope.

Comment: @JohnMoeller That definition only specifies two _points_. I'm asking whether we can strengthen the condition to two _vertices_.

Comment: Would you please provide us with your definition of a polygon?

Comment: I think the first question might follow from choosing one of the vertices that have the interior angle greater than $\pi$, triangulating the polygon and checking the value against what is known. That is, for a convex polygon, we know the interior angle has to equal $(n-2)\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}$ from triangulation. I haven't put a ton of thought into it, but this is what I'm thinking.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat A closed plane figure with straight line boundaries. Feel free to use any reasonable definition of polygon you wish though. A convex polygon is a polygon for which the interior is a convex set.

Comment: @EuYu Changing the condition to two vertices actually *weakens* it, not strengthens it. Vertices are points too; therefore it is satisfied.

Comment: @JoeZeng Indeed it does, thank you.

Comment: @Clayton I'm not too sure what you mean. The interior angles of any simple polygon sums to $(n-2)\frac{\pi}{2}$ regardless of concave or convex.

Comment: @EuYu: I'm not entirely sure of it. I haven't had a chance to think about it. When I have a mental block (studying for prelims), I'll come back here to think about your problem.

Comment: I think your question may be equivalent to the following: Given any two rays that meet at a point, the line segment that connects any two points on the ray will always be on the side of the two rays with a smaller angle. Then a polygon is simply the intersection of a bunch of these two-ray configurations.

Comment: Note that any proof will have to inherently use the simplicity of the polygon, because the theorem isn't true for self-intersecting polygons - imagine taking a heart-shaped (cardiod) loop that wraps twice around the origin and polygonalizing it.

Comment: @EuYu do you mean "$(n-2)\pi$", right?

Comment: It's been a really long time, but I'm wondering if there's been any updates (i.e. if you've found a proof of this fact). Side note: Terry Tao in his Complex Analysis notes assigns this as an exercise (Ex. 58), and apparently there's a proof using some sort of "continuity argument": https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/10/02/math-246a-notes-3-cauchys-theorem-and-its-consequences

Comment: @D.R. I posted a proof at [Sufficient criteria for proving convexity of a polygon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3517341/sufficient-criteria-for-proving-convexity-of-a-polygon/3525337).

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I did like your proof, but it is difficult to formalize the step where you split of the exterior of P into a polygon Q that shares many vertices with P. I would like a proof using as few "geometric arguments" as possible, just perhaps the existence of a bounded interior given by the Jordan Curve Theorem. That's why I think Tao's "continuity argument" sounds most promising.

Comment: @D.R. The existence of $Q$ follows from the Jordan Curve Theorem: it’s the intersection of the interiors of the two curves obtained by walking from $A$ along the segment to $B$ and then around the boundary of the polygon in one of the two directions back to $A$. Since $AB$ is exterior to $P$, there’s a path from $∞$ that crosses $AB$ without touching $P$, and its endpoint lies in the interior of both curves, so $Q$ is nonempty.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose a concave polyhedron exists so that all vertex connections produce lines entirely inside the polyhedron.

Since the object is concave, there are points on two faces with a connecting segment outside of the polyhedron. Now consider the hull of the points for just these two faces.  The connecting segment must be inside this hull. Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

I will formulate my answer for general convex sets in vector spaces. Then convex closed polytopes (polygons) on the place accrue as a special case.

If $C$ is a convex set on a vector space $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ (One can easily generalise these facts to infinite-dimensional spaces) and $x\in\partial C$ (the boundary of $C$) then, there is a line $\mathcal{H}=\{x| Hx = K\}$ that supports $C$ at $x$, i.e. for all $x\in C$ it is $Hx\leq K$ and for $x\notin C$ it is $Hx>K$ (The relation $\leq$ is meant as the element-wise order of vectors of $X$.) This supporting hyperplane in the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a line, i.e. its angle is $\pi$.

The angle you mentioned is actually the polar angle of the tangent cone $T_C(x)$ wheneven $x$ is a vertex of $C$. If $x$ is not a vertex $T_C(x)$ is a supporting hyper-plane; in general it is a cone that lies completely in a supporting plane of $C$ at $x$, so its angle is less than or equal to $\pi$. This proves your claim in a more general setting.

Back to your question again... you may also use purely Euclidean arguments (In Euclidean geometry by the way, $A_1A_2\ldots A_n$ is convex if it contains all line segments that can be drawn from its vertices. Assume that $\widehat{A_kA_{k+1} A_{k+2}}>180^\circ$. Then $A_kA_{k+2}$ has all its points outside the polygon.

Comment: I must say that I am much more interested in the Euclidean proof. The last paragraph you provided is one direction of my first claim. Do you have any idea how to prove the converse? If all interior angles are less than $\pi$ then the polygon is convex.