# Sufficient criteria for proving convexity of a polygon

Tags: euclidean-geometry, polygons, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

We define a 2D polygon to be a simple (ie. non-self-intersecting) closed path consisting of line segments. To be clear, only consecutive segments intersect and only at an endpoint. Moreover, we do not include polygons such that consecutive sides lie on the same line. A convex polygon is defined as a polygon that is a convex set (ie. if we define the interior of the polygon to include the boundary, the segment formed by joining any two points in the interior lies in the interior).

It is easy to prove that the following two conditions are necessary for convexity, but how can we prove that they are sufficient as well?

1. Every diagonal (ie. segment created by joining two vertices) lies in the interior of the polygon.
2. Every interior angle is strictly less than $180^{\circ}$.

Comment: Do you want to prove that a (simple) polygon is convex if and only if every interior angle is less than $180°$? - [Proof of an obvious fact about convex polygons.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/259031/318073)

Comment: Yes, and I came across that link but did not find a complete answer. Did you find something in that link?

Answer (score 2):

It’s clear that 1 implies 2, so let’s prove that 2 implies the polygon is convex.

Given a polygon $P$ with every interior angle less than $180^\circ$, suppose to the contrary that part of a segment between interior points goes outside $P$.  Let $AB$ be one of these outside parts with $A, B$ on the boundary of $P$.  Then $AB$ divides the exterior of $P$ into two regions, one of which is a finite polygon $Q$.

Consider the vertex of $Q$ farthest from $AB$.  It’s not $A$ or $B$, so its interior angle is an exterior angle of $P$ and must be greater than $180^\circ$.  But that means we must be able travel in some direction interior to $Q$ that strictly increases the distance from $AB$.  And for any interior point, there must be another vertex of $Q$ at least as far as that from $AB$.  This contradicts our choice of the farthest vertex.

Therefore, there is no such segment and $P$ is convex.

Comment: I'm having a extremely hard time visualizing this proof; what regions does P get divided into?

Comment: @user118161 The *exterior* of $P$ gets divided, not $P$.

Comment: I like this answer, but I wonder if there is a way to make it "completely rigorous": you commented in the other question that there are two polygons $P_1$ and $P_2$ defined by taking the path along $A\to B$ and then one of the two paths along $P$ going back $B \to A$. We then define $Q_I$ by the intersection of the interiors of $P_1,P_2$ (using JCT), but then we need to show that the boundary of $Q_I$ is a polygon whose vertices are all either $A,B$ or a vertex of $P$.

Comment: Then about the interior/exterior angles: I want to use the definition "interior angle of vertex $v_j$ is $<180$" to be "the straight line $(1-t)v_j + tv_{j+1}, t\in [0,1]$ can be extended to $t\in (1,1+\delta)$ s.t. the extended portion lies (completely) in the exterior of $P$". If your proof can be modified to address these "complaints", then I will consider the proof to be "completely rigorous". Of course, you don't have to spend your time on this; I just wanted to think about how to make your answer absolutely airtight.

Comment: @D.R. Although we could prove $Q_I$ to be a polygon interior, we don’t strictly need to; a nonempty finite union of disjoint polygon interiors would suffice. It’s nonempty for the reason I gave in my [other comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259031/proving-that-a-closed-simple-polygon-in-the-plane-is-convex-if-and-only-if-all-t#comment8922797_259031). I’m content to rely on someone else’s proof that a finite intersection of polygon interiors is a finite union of disjoint polygon interiors, and basic definitions/theorems about angles; these aren’t an obstacle to formalization.